send multicast but only local can read
I have 2 different machine example is 192.168.11.115 and 192.168.11.114
Machine 192.168.11.114 will send video stream to multicast address 239.0.0.1 and port 1234
And I want machine 192.168.11.115 can't read from above multicast address and only 192.168.11.114 can read it
Im using libuv and c++
This is code I using to send video stream to multicast address
struct sockaddr_in send_addr;
uv_ip4_addr("239.0.0.1", 1234, &send_addr);

uv_buf_t buf = uv_buf_init((char*)message, len);

uv_udp_send_t* send_req = new uv_udp_send_t;
uv_udp_send(send_req, &_udpSend, &buf, 1, reinterpret_cast<const struct sockaddr*>(&send_addr), on_send);

And this is I init uv_udp_t
status = uv_udp_init(_loop, &_udpSend);
struct sockaddr_in send_addr;
uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 1111, &send_addr);
uv_udp_bind(&_udpSend, (const struct sockaddr*)&send_addr, UV_UDP_REUSEADDR);
// uv_udp_set_multicast_interface(&_udpSend, "192.168.11.114");
// uv_udp_set_membership(&_udpSend, "239.0.0.1", "192.168.11.114", UV_JOIN_GROUP);
uv_udp_recv_start(&_udpSend, on_alloc, on_recv);

I have try set multicast interface but its not work. And I know I can send unicast but the player not support play unicast video stream

Unless you've encrypted the steam then by definition anyone on the network can see your multicast stream, the only thing you could conceivably do is configure your switch to ignore the igmp from some addresses but I'm not aware of switches having that feature

I found solution that add multicast interface with local ip to make multicast only work with local ip
uv_udp_set_multicast_interface(&_udpSend, "127.0.0.1");
uv_udp_set_membership(&_udpSend, "239.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1", UV_JOIN_GROUP);

